# Why doesn't the Weierstrass approximation theorem imply that every continuous function can be written as a power series?

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

I hope that my question in the title is well formulated.

I am a little bit confused with the next exercise from a book:

Argue that there exists functions $f \in C[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ that cannot be written on the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^k, x\in(0, \frac{1}{2}).
$$

But Weierstrass' theorem states that $||f(x)-P(x)||_{\infty} < \epsilon$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial for $x\in[a,b]$.

The statement of the exercises refers to an open and bounded interval, and in Weierstrass to a closed and bounded interval for the polynomial. Is this the key? to be honest, I do not see why.

Comment: The title asks something else than the body of the question. Tim answered the question in the title and Davide the question in the body. A better title might be: "Why doesn't the Weierstrass approximation theorem imply that every continuous function can be written as a power series?"

Comment: I Agree :P. I have changed the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weierstrass theorem tells that on a compact interval, given a continuous function, there is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to this function. But the polynomials are not necessarily of the form $\sum_{j=0}^{N_n}c_jx^j$, because *the coefficients depend on $n$*. They are indeed of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{N_n}c_{n,k}x^k$.

To get a concrete example, consider $\left|x-\frac 12\right|$. This cannot be written as a power series, because this function would be differentiable at $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, it is really illustrative. Then my problem is that I can not see why polynomials can not be necessarily of the form of power series. Any example or reference?

Comment: I see your point, after reading twice "the coefficients also depends on n for the sequence". Foe me, the question is solved. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

think about $f(x) = \frac 1x$.

On any closed interval $[a,b]$ with $a>0$ the function is bounded and I can approximate it very well with a polynomial.

But on the open interval $(0,1)$ it's unbounded.  The reason I can get away with this is because it's not defined at $0$.  Any continuous function on a closed interval is bounded.  That's not true on open intervals.

That's why Weierstrass can't help with open intervals. For the answer to the homework problem I'll refer you to Davide Giraudo's answer which has just popped up. (Which is much easier than proving that $\frac 1x$ can't be written as a polynomial.)

Comment: This is not what the question is asking, it seems.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for your answer. But the domain of $f$ in my example is closed. I am currently looking at the answer of Davide to see if I am able of understand it. Nevertheless, I see why Weierstrass can not be applied to $f \in C(a, b)$.

Comment: I was obviously confused by your previous title.   Although you still claim that the statement of the exercise refers to an open and bounded interval.  Anyway, I'm glad you've solved it.